# Why is LIBOR rate smoother than the US treasury rate?

Tags: interest-rates, libor, treasuries

Compare the daily rate graphs of [LIBOR](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/?id=USD3MTD156N,) and [US Treasury bill](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/?id=DTB3,), the former is a lot smoother than the latter. Is there any reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the Bill rate is observed from an active marketplace with billions of dollars of transactions, whereas Libor is the result of a daily poll of large banks, who tend to move the rate gradually and smoothly over time.